# Anchor tag href first and then onclick

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to execute **href** first and then **onclick** event, of anchor tag?

```
frameDoc.body.innerHTML+='<div style="margin-left:10;"><li class="highlight"><a href="'+tmp1+'"  onclick="highlightSearch(this);">'+searched_headings[l]+'</a></li></div>';
```

1.First open the link
2.Then process the onclick function.

Please suggest me...

Comment: If you want to do this I suggest put this on click in your new opened html's ready event.

Comment: what is the link contain? and any fiddle?

Comment: Dear whale_steward, the link 'tmp1' is a just html file name like 'abc.htm'

Comment: Hello syms, i am very new to javascript. you are saying that i have to put the function in opened html file's onload event..right...or give me some example...please...

Comment: yeah you are right. I assume you are redirecting page from your application only.

Answer (score 1):

No, thats not possible, the click event executes first and then you will be redirected to the page you specified in `href` attribute of anchor tag. So, instead you could add in extra query parameters in your href and then on the new page check those parameters and execute the click event from the new page. For example::

```
//tmp1 is your href
var tmp1 = "http://www.somesite.com/somepage";
//add query parameter
tmp1 += "?doSomething=1";
```

on redirecting to the new page, check for `doSomething` and execute the click event.